# How do I send data from Data Loggers to Azure IoT Hub or AWS IoT?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, send, iot

I want to send my data to either MS Azure or AWS IoT platform through my Data Logger.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure IoT Hub exposes device endpoints:

> #### Device endpoints
>
> For each device provisioned in the device identity registry, IoT Hub exposes a set of endpoints that a device can use to send and receive messages:
>
> - Send **device-to-cloud** messages. Use this endpoint to send device-to-cloud messages.
> - Receive cloud-to-device messages. A device uses this endpoint to receive targeted cloud-to-device messages.
>
> [...]
>
> These endpoints are exposed using **MQTT v3.1.1, HTTP 1.1, and AMQP 1.0 protocols**. Note that AMQP is also available over WebSockets on port 443.

The simplest way would be a REST call:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt590784.aspx

> `POST https://{IoTHubName}.azure-devices.net/devices/{deviceId}/messages/events?api-version={api-version}`
>
> The body can be any octet-stream. Note that the size of the whole message (body plus properties) has to be less than 256 Kb.

e.g.

```sh
$ curl -X POST https://heresthething.azure-devices.net/devices/aNewArduino/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03 \
       -H "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=HeresTheThing.azure-devices.net&sig=t8Pf2lXXXVDlMY%3d&se=1489585285&skn=device" \
       -H "Transfer-Encoding: Chunked" \
       -H "Connection: Close" \
       -k -v \
       --data "New Arduino, who dis?"
```

Use [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/releases) to register your device(s) and generate SAS.

You should start here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-devguide/

Depening on the scale of your project (2 devices or 2000?), you may want something less complex, like [App Service Mobile Apps with Easy Tables](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/). It's essentially a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) API.

A `POST` is all you need to ingest telemetry. You can then use *OData v3* syntax to `GET` and filter your data set.

[image: Zumo-GET-sample]

Comment: the API link is broken, I could get some @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device-messaging-rest-apis